# DynamoDB : How to query multiple partition key ordered by sort key on GSI

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm currently developing an Instagram clone using dynamoDB and appSync as back-end.

Im currently working on the user's feed page. I need to query all posts by the user and the users he follows ordered by timestamp.

I created a GSI with userId as partition key and timestamp as sort key.

I tried:

- "Query" on GSI, but it allow only one partition key
- "Scan" on the GSI then filter on userId, but it doesn't order posts by timestamp
- "BatchGet", but it doesn't order posts by timestamp, and the result is not flatten

Post Attributes:

```
{
    type:"POST",
    id:"post1",
    timeStamp:"213213123",
    img_url: "https://img.com/img.jpg",
    userComment:"nice pic",
    userId:"user1",
    userName:"kevin",
    numberOfComment:"0",
    numberOfLike:"0
}
```

User attribute:

```
{
    type:"USER",
    id:"user1",
    userName:"Kevin",
    FollowerCount:0,
    FollowCount:0,
    PostCount:1,
    bio:"bio"
}
```

Is there another solution?

edit: my dynamodbTable

[image: my dynamoDb Table]

Comment: How many tables you have. 2 ? u probably need to add your table details.

Comment: Worth reading the blog post at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-sort-keys-to-organize-data-in-amazon-dynamodb/, particularly the chat message app example.

Comment: I have only one Table. I can fetch all posts by userId with by querying the userId-timeStamp-index